# How to define multiple ports in Prometheus EC2 Service Discovery Config (ec2_sd_config)

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

The EC2 SD config accepts the following parameters.

```
ec2_sd_configs:
  - region: us-west-2
    access_key: OMITTED
    secret_key: OMITTED
    port: 9101
```

I want to scrape metrics from ports 9101 and 9182. To do this i defined the ec2_sd_config twice and list access and secret keys twice. Is there a way I can add multiple ports from one config?

```
    ec2_sd_configs:
      - region: us-west-2
        access_key:
        secret_key:
        port: 9101
​
      - region: us-west-2
        access_key:
        secret_key:
        port: 9182
```

Answer (score 0):

`ec2_sd_configs` is meant for instance discovery, not process discovery.

For example, running a node or process exporter on each EC2 machine, hosted on a single port, on every instance.

You'll need to use a separate service discovery mechanism such as the http / Consul one to more dynamically gather/discover separate process ports on every instance.

Comment: any examples that combine both ec2 discovery and process discovery @onecricketeer

Comment: @AnNguyen Install some exporter on each EC2 instance that'll get that data. These all run on the same port. Then discover and scrape those with ec2_sd_config

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar challenge.

Port 9100 for Linux
Port 9182 for windows

What I did is override the windows port to listen on 9100, so that I can use only one ec2_sd_configs.

```
ec2_sd_configs:
  - region: us-west-2
    access_key:
    secret_key:
    port: 9100
```

Command I used to overide windows port is:

> choco install prometheus-windows-exporter.install --params '"/ListenPort:9100"' --force -y

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
  - job_name: linux
    ec2_sd_configs: &ec2config
     - region: <region>
       access_key: <your_access_key>
       secret_key: <your_secret_key>
    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_type]
      regex: linux
      action: keep
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_private_ip]
      regex: '(.*)'
      replacement: '${1}:9101'
      target_label: __address__
  - job_name: windows
    ec2_sd_configs: *ec2config
    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_type]
      regex: windows
      action: keep
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_private_ip]
      regex: '(.*)'
      replacement: '${1}:9182'
      target_label: __address__
```

We defined two jobs (`linux` and `windows`) and filtered EC2 instances based on tags, but this can be changed to your needs.
Job with name `windows` will **reuse** `ec2config` service discovery from `linux` job, so Prometheus will **reduce** API calls to AWS.